# Inheritance with new ActivityResult launcher

Tags: java, android, startactivityforresult

Before `startActivityForResult` was deprecated I had a base Activity and I needed to make sure that all activities that inherit from that showcase a specific behaviour every time they would call that method. So I had the following code in my base Activity:

```
 @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_right_in, R.anim.exit_left_out);

    }
```

Every Activity that inherits from the base one, shows that specific animation every time it calls `startActivityForResult`

Using a launcher though, I had to add the above animation in every single one of my child Activities. Is there a way to still have the inheritance I had before where all launchers override the one from the base activity?